# Is there a way to create a global variable from a firestore Stream<DocumentSnapshot> that updates itself?

Tags: dart, flutter, stream, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making an e commerce app and have all the prices in a Map in firestore. I was looking forward to make a global variable that can be accessed from every part of the app and that updates if there's a change in the database.

What I'm trying to avoid is using StreamBuilder everytime I need to access a price.

I'm been trying to come up with a solution but every way I've found of dealing with firestore is using the StreamBuilder method, and I can't find a way of turning that into a variable.

I know my explanation may have been a little messy. But basically what Im trying to do is " Map price = 'Map in firestore' "

Any ideas? I'm new in flutter, so thanks to everyone in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to use StreamBuilder in everywhere if you want reactive widgets. Because if the data update itself, so your widget has state, because of that you need a StatefulWidget(StreamBuilder is a StatefulWidget).

Imagine you get the variable you want, even so you'll still need a StreamBuilder similars like FutureBuilder or ScopedModelDescendant(if you use ScopedModel) or Provider(if you use provider package) and the list is go on depending on which package you use...

Don't be afraid of using them. If you make rest of the page StatelessWidget, you won't notice any performance issue probably.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was actually thinking of using Provider... Maybe I'm getting too peaky of separating Logic from UI components haha... 
Thanks again! Have a great day!

Comment: Welcome, don't forget to closing the topic via accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Inherited Widgets.

Watch this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zbm3hjPjQMk

You can read the data when your App starts using BLoC to separate the data from the UI. It is explained here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fahC3ky_zW0